# Apple-SignIn issue when using clientId in Web

Tags: apple-sign-in

In web apple-sign-in, using apple-sign Embed Sign in with Apple JS and using `bundleId` in the place of `MyAppClientId` but always getting error Invalid Client Id in Apple Sign-In popup.

```js
AppleID.auth.init({ 
clientId : MyAppClientId, 
scope : "email", 
redirectURI : "https://test.com", 
state : "signin", 
usePopup : true });
```

Is there any way when we can use `bundleId` in web apple login process

How can we configure on Web logo in place of Apple logo in login popup

In my website, configure Apple sign-in but unable to proceed due to invlaid_client issue